# setting maximum length in a gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Greetings Everyone..i just wanna ask is it possible to set a maximum length in my field in gridview?

Below is my gridview sample that retrieve a formatted html in my database..All i want to achieve is to limit the maximum length of characters i.e "50" then automatically create a pagination for the succeeding characters..to be posted in the gridview

```
 <div id="GridScroll" class="grid_scroll">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="None" 
        GridLines="None"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="308px" Width="1174px" ShowHeader="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="NewsText" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal EnableViewState="false" ID="literal1" Text='<%# Bind("NewsText") %>' mode="PassThrough" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Any advise or suggestion is highly sought...thank you

Comment: pagination in grid is depend upon pagesize and ispaging property enabled or disabled,so set page size=1 or something else, and be sure the number of rows you bind to gridview.

Comment: First.. thanks for the response Ramakrishman.. but i already tried your advised and still i don't achieve my desired output..

Answer (score 1):

use this in the test property of literal

```
Text='<%# Bind("NewsText").ToString().Substring(0, 50) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set fixed width on asp:Literal object

Comment: i don't get it.. i don't even see a width property in my literal...if you don't mind.. can you please show me how? is this a function or something..thanks

Comment: Agree with @Kid -- the Literal control is to include literal code (HTML, CSS, Javascript...). To your possible point, you could literally include a width formatting directive by adding this to the Text property of the literal: style="width:1234px;" or something like that.